# GIven a list of locations of residents, need to find K locations such that it minimises the sum of abs diff b/w the selected location and A[i]

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

following Question is assigmnet for my course in college
[Problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7NFJ.png)

Following is the code i tried for the question.

```
from math import ceil, floor
 
n = 0
 
def cost(i, j, p,c):
    if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
        c[i][j] =  p[j] - p[int((i + j) / 2)] - p[int((i + j) / 2) - 1] + p[i - 1]
    else:
        c[i][j] =  p[j] - 2 * p[int((i + j - 1) / 2)] + p[i - 1]
    return c[i][j]
 
def minCost(A, k):    
    if k >= n:
        return 0
    
    p = [0] * (n + 1)
    pos = []
    c = [[0] * (n + 1) for _ in range(n + 1)]
 
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        p[i] = p[i - 1] + A[i - 1]
    
    D = [[float('inf')] * (k + 1) for _ in range(n + 1)]
    
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        D[i][1] = cost(1, i, p,c)
    
    for j in range(1, k + 1):
        D[0][j] = 0
    
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(2, k + 1):
            for i0 in range(1, i + 1):
                temp = D[i][j]
                D[i][j] = min(D[i][j], D[i0 - 1][j - 1] + cost(i0, i, p,c))
                

    print(D)
    for j in range(k, 0, -1):
        for i in range(n, 0, -1):
            found = False
            for i0 in range(i, 0, -1):
                if D[i0 - 1][j - 1] == float('inf'):
                    D[i0 - 1][j - 1] = 0
                if D[i][j] == (D[i0 - 1][j - 1] + c[i0][i]):
                    if A[i0-1] not in pos:
                        pos.append(A[i0-1])
                        found = True
                        break
            if found == True:
                break
                    
 
    
   
    
    return D[n][k], pos
 
# Example usage:
A = [1,2,3,7,8,9]
k = 2
n = len(A)
result, positions = minCost(A, k)
print("Minimum cost:", result)
print("Positions of testing centers:", positions)
```

The answer for above example is minimum cost  = 4 and positions 2,8

while i am able to get the correct minimum cost =4, but the positions i am getting is 1,7.
can someone point out the mistake i might be doing in my code?, i am using DP to solve the problem.